Turing Machine transition table for checking a palindrome
Using a Turing machine. If the input tape of the machine consisted of a string of 0's and 1's, how would you approach the problem given that the output of the machine should be 1 or 0 respectively depending if it's a palindrome or not.
I'm really struggling to get my head round the idea.
Any guidance is much appreciated.
I tried working out the idea in my head and on paper for example:
1, 0, 1, 0, 1
I would start at 1 in state "start" and then check the symbol. In this example, the symbol is 1, so I would set the symbol to a new "marked" symbol and move to the right in a new state called "compare_right_1", in this state the machine would reach the end and read a blank symbol and hence reach the end of the tape, so move left and check the symbol for a 1, if the symbol is a 1 then move to the next space on the left, if not then quit as its not a palindrome.
I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Turing machines aren't computer programming, they're theoretical computer science. [cs.se] would be a better place to ask.


I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

I confirm it is the correct approach.
There are the following transitions for matching a leftside zero with one at the right end:



current state
symbol read
symbol to write
direction to move
new state




start
0
blank
right
findRight0


start
1
blank
right
findRight1


start
blank
copy
right
accept


findRight0
0,1
copy
right
findRight0


findRight0
blank
copy
left
matchRight0


matchRight0
0
blank
left
reverseStart


matchRight0
1
copy
left
reject


matchRight0
blank
copy
left
accept



Add these transitions for when we need to match a lefside one instead of a zero (see above findRight1):



current state
symbol read
symbol to write
direction to move
new state




findRight1
0,1
copy
right
findRight1


findRight1
blank
copy
left
matchRight1


matchRight1
0
copy
left
reject


matchRight1
1
blank
left
reverseStart


matchRight1
blank
copy
left
accept



Similarly we can do all this for the opposite direction:



current state
symbol read
symbol to write
direction to move
new state




reverseStart
0
blank
left
findLeft0


reverseStart
1
blank
left
findLeft1


reverseStart
blank
copy
left
accept


findLeft0
0,1
copy
left
findLeft0


findLeft0
blank
copy
right
matchLeft0


matchLeft0
0
blank
right
start


matchLeft0
1
copy
right
reject


matchLeft0
blank
copy
right
accept


findLeft1
0,1
copy
left
findLeft1


findLeft1
blank
copy
right
matchLeft1


matchLeft1
0
copy
right
reject


matchLeft1
1
blank
right
start


matchLeft1
blank
copy
right
accept



NB: If you wanted to keep the number of states down, you could just walk to the left side of the input without further logic, and then repeat from the start state. It would make the duration of the execution about twice as long.
Here is an snippet running an implementation of a Turing machine using that transition table. You can play with the input to see what you get:


createTuring({
  transitions: [
    { state: "start",        read: "0", write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "findRight0" },
    { state: "start",        read: "1", write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "findRight1" },
    { state: "start",        read: "_",             move: "R", nextState: "accept" },
    { state: "findRight0",   read: "01",            move: "R", nextState: "findRight0" },
    { state: "findRight0",   read: "_",             move: "L", nextState: "matchRight0" },
    { state: "matchRight0",  read: "0", write: "_", move: "L", nextState: "reverseStart" },
    { state: "matchRight0",  read: "1",             move: "L", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "matchRight0",  read: "_",             move: "L", nextState: "accept" },
    { state: "findRight1",   read: "01",            move: "R", nextState: "findRight1" },
    { state: "findRight1",   read: "_",             move: "L", nextState: "matchRight1" },
    { state: "matchRight1",  read: "0",             move: "L", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "matchRight1",  read: "1", write: "_", move: "L", nextState: "reverseStart" },
    { state: "matchRight1",  read: "_",             move: "L", nextState: "accept" },
    { state: "reverseStart", read: "0", write: "_", move: "L", nextState: "findLeft0" },
    { state: "reverseStart", read: "1", write: "_", move: "L", nextState: "findLeft1" },
    { state: "reverseStart", read: "_",             move: "L", nextState: "accept" },
    { state: "findLeft0",    read: "01",            move: "L", nextState: "findLeft0" },
    { state: "findLeft0",    read: "_",             move: "R", nextState: "matchLeft0" },
    { state: "matchLeft0",   read: "0", write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "start" },
    { state: "matchLeft0",   read: "1",             move: "R", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "matchLeft0",   read: "_",             move: "R", nextState: "accept" },
    { state: "findLeft1",    read: "01",            move: "L", nextState: "findLeft1" },
    { state: "findLeft1",    read: "_",             move: "R", nextState: "matchLeft1" },
    { state: "matchLeft1",   read: "0",             move: "R", nextState: "reject" },
    { state: "matchLeft1",   read: "1", write: "_", move: "R", nextState: "start" },
    { state: "matchLeft1",   read: "_",             move: "R", nextState: "accept" },
  ],
  initState: "start",
  tape: "10110001101",
});
<script src="https://trincot.github.io/turing.js"></script>



